# How do I dewarp fisheye (Samsung Gear 360) photos?

Tags: samsung, image-processing, photography

Samsung Gear 360 is a dual-spherical 180+180 fishey lens setup for full vertical+horizontal 360* panarama or virtual reality photography.

On windows, one can use Cyberlink power director to import & dewarp the photos.

What is the workflow on linux/ubuntu?

[image]

EDIT: the generalized fisheye solutions do not work, so this is not a duplicate, because 360 fisheyes aren't mere lens distortions but require a complex equirectangular stitch that is not a simple process.

Comment: See http://paulbourke.net/dome/fish2/  https://developer.nvidia.com/vrworks/vrworks-360video and https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29883&iTestingId=83109

Comment: Not a duplicate, see edit note

Answer (score 2):

Running

> ls -1 path/to/files/*.JPG | parallel --load 99% --noswap --memfree 500M --bar ./[gear360pano.sh](https://github.com/ultramango/gear360pano) {}

seems to work, and the packaged html viewer shows an interactive panorama once the python server is launched. Very nice